# Visual Studio Code GIT Not Working

Tags: windows-10, git, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-code

So I installed GIT and I'm in a GIT repository and I added a simple test file in the folder. I'm trying to connect to Azure DevOps. My Source Control says that I have made some changes, but it doesn't display those changes. Does anyone know why?

Visual Studio Code - version: 1.39.1

OS: Windows_NY x64 10.0.17763

Tfvc: Location - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crPyB.png)

Comment: Have you installed any of the GIT extensions for VSCode

Comment: I have the builtin GIT enabled and 'Azure Repos'  installed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the information you provided, you have a clone of a repository but you are not connected to one.  Below is what you should see if you are connect to a DevOps reporsitory.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRuqo.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRuqo.png]

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed. It was a bug in VS Code.

[VS Code September update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJPci.png)